# Find image strings with Regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, string, replace, find, notepad++

Please provide a generic syntax that can be used to scan any type of image string, where, all that has to be done is pass in the correct file type extension to get the match.  A more ideal approach, though not required, would be a way to pass in more than one file extension type.

The following is generated when navigating to a file directory in a Google Chrome browser:

```
Name    Size    Date Modified
[parent directory]      
BamboNature.jpg 40.0 kB 10/22/15, 2:42:00 PM
bjs1.jpg    80.7 kB 10/22/15, 3:04:55 PM
BroodyChick.jpg 55.2 kB 10/22/15, 2:42:16 PM
EarthsBest01.jpg    95.9 kB 10/22/15, 3:04:38 PM
HonestDiaper.jpg    42.5 kB 10/22/15, 2:42:29 PM
Huggies_1.jpg   44.3 kB 10/22/15, 3:04:28 PM
Huggies_2.jpg   46.7 kB 10/22/15, 3:04:02 PM
Luvs_2.jpg  53.0 kB 10/22/15, 2:01:07 PM
Luvs.jpg    49.6 kB 10/22/15, 3:03:48 PM
Munchkin.jpg    40.6 kB 10/22/15, 3:03:31 PM
Pampers.jpg 49.6 kB 10/22/15, 3:03:24 PM
Pampers02.jpg   40.2 kB 10/22/15, 3:03:15 PM
parents-choice-unscented-ba.jpg 42.6 kB 10/22/15, 2:45:16 PM
Target-diapers.jpg  41.0 kB 10/22/15, 2:43:05 PM
Thumbs.db   63.5 kB 10/22/15, 3:06:20 PM
```

The desired output would be a to remove everything save for the images, which, in this case, all have the `.jpg` file extension type.

**Intended result**:

```
BamboNature.jpg
bjs1.jpg
BroodyChick.jpg
EarthsBest01.jpg
HonestDiaper.jpg
Huggies_1.jpg
Huggies_2.jpg
Luvs_2.jpg
Luvs.jpg
Munchkin.jpg
Pampers.jpg
Pampers02.jpg
parents-choice-unscented-ba.jpg
Target-diapers.jpg
```

Again, this should be able to be applied for any file type and will be a standalone regex to remove clutter from file directory listings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use a regular expression like this. I wrote it so it can even do file names that contain a space in them. Remember to turn on multi-line if you are doing the whole text at the same time.

```
^.*?\.\S{1,3}
```

description

```
  ^.*?\.\S{1,3}
      Beginning of line or string
      Any character, any number of repetitions, as few as possible
      Literal .
      Anything other than whitespace, between 1 and 3 repetition
```

Particularly for notepad++, you can use the find&replace feature use these. make sure you Untick the ". matches newline" then do:

```
Find what    : (^.*?\.\S{1,3})(.*)
Replace with : \1
```

Comment: I tested and it works.  Could you also add the customization for targeting specific file types as well.  The regex you provided did not remove the `thumbs.db` though it should have.  I'm basically asking for the syntax for literals and where to apply it.

Comment: you said it should be used for "ANY FILE TYPE". a .db is still a file type. But if you want to specify the exact extensions. remove the "\S{1,3}" (without the quotes) part and replace with "(jpg|png|gif)" (without the quotes). Make sure you don't match the case, because otherwise, JPG, jPg and jpg are all different extensions.

Comment: What would the syntax be to "invert" the regex you provided.  That is, remove the images and keep the junk?

Comment: The replace with can be change to reference the capture group. A capture group is simply the set of things that are inside of a parenthesis. change the replace with to a \2  or  \3   to reference a different capture group.